# Opencv imread a frame

Tags: opencv, imread

I have recently used this piece of code to save frame data from a webcam

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
if (!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
    return -1;

cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 15);

Mat edges;
namedWindow("image", 1);
std::vector<cv::Mat> images(100);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    // this is optional, preallocation so there's no allocation
    // during capture
    images[i].create(480, 640, CV_8UC3);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
    frame.copyTo(images[i]);
}
cap.release();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    imshow("image", images[i]);
    if (waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
}
```

After this, I want to use imread to analyse the newly splitted frames. However, I cannot think of a way to accomplish this.

I tried: `Mat colorImage = imread(images[i]);`

However, it leads to:

`error C2664: 'cv::Mat cv::imread(const cv::String &,int)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::vector<cv::Mat,std::allocator<_Ty>>' to 'const cv::String &'
with
[
    _Ty=cv::Mat
]`

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imread function is used to open the image from disk.

You already have vector of images so you just do:

Mat colorImage = images[i];

and btw. there is no need for this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    // this is optional, preallocation so there's no allocation
    // during capture
    images[i].create(480, 640, CV_8UC3);
}
```

because you are allocating new space anyway except you capture the frames directly like this:

```
cap >> images[i];
```